# Separar proyectos angular en subproyectos

Tags: angular

Estoy llevando a cabo un proyecto el cual tendrá una gran escalabilidad y crecerá en función de años bastante.

A la hora de establecer una arquitectura del proyecto se ha pensando en utilizar ngRX pero nos planteamos una duda la cual nos tiene bloqueados.

El proyecto lo tendremos diferenciado entre distintos módulos. A la hora de establecer un desarrollo, ¿Veis mejor tener TODOS los módulos en un mismo proyecto, (puede ser entre 200 o 300 módulos) o sería conveniente tener un proyecto base e ir importando módulos, los cuales se desarrollarían independientemente como nuevas aplicaciones angular?.

Toda la documentación que encontramos recomiendan tenerlo todo en un mismo proyecto, pero la otra opción pensamos que facilita el desarrollo al equipo.

Comment: Esta pregunta no encaja en la temática de este foro, ya que sólo podemos contestarte con opiniones. Según tengas desacoplado tu proyecto, así podrás plantearte el dividirlo en subproyectos. Con servicios comunes y usando rutas, no debe ser complicado. Lo que no es recomendable es importar cientos de módulos de golpe. Crea más servicios.

Comment: Si vas a desarrollar **nuevas** aplicaciones angular, los módulos no están preparados para ello. Angular provee formas de agrupar aplicaciones en un mismo *workspace*: `ng new` genera un workspace y `ng generate application` genera una aplicación dentro de un workspace. Dicho esto yo me plantearía **no desarrollar módulos como nuevas aplicaciones, sino expandir tu aplicación actual con uso correcto de los módulos**